# show 2 divs next to each other instead of pushing the one on a new row

Tags: jquery, css, materialize

I have 2 divs in a menu that are hidden and displayed on click. I want them to display side by side, same row as in the second picture, instead of getting pushed on a new row. I'm using materializecss.

[image]
[image]

This is the markup:

```js
$('#location-filter').on('click', function(e) {
  $('#locationFilter').toggle('1000');
  $('.location-filter').toggleClass('fa-angle-down fa-times');
});

$('.length-filter').on('click', function(e) {
  $('#lengthFilter').toggle('1000');
  $('.length-filter').toggleClass('fa-angle-down fa-times');
});

$('.price-filter').on('click', function(e) {
  $('#priceFilter').toggle('1000');
  $('.price-filter').toggleClass('fa-angle-down fa-times');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col s12 m2 push-m1">
  <div class="input-field">
    <input class="select-dropdown length-input-filter lengthFilterInput" id="length-slider-toggler" type="text" readonly="true" value="Längd">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-down length-filter filter length-filter-icon"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="card studiecentralen-transparency" id="lengthFilter" style="display: none;">
    <div class="card-content">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="length-slider"></div>
        <div id="length-values" class="mt-2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col m7 offset-m5">
  <div class="card studiecentralen-transparency" id="locationFilter" style="display: none;">
    <div class="card-content">
      <div class="row">
        <label class="col m2">
                                                <input type="checkbox" />
                                                <span>Blekinge</span>
                                            </label>
        <label class="col m2">
                                                <input type="checkbox" />
                                                <span>Dalarna</span>
                                            </label>
        <label class="col m2">
                                                <input type="checkbox" />
                                                <span>Gotland</span>
                                            </label>
        <label class="col m2">
                                                <input type="checkbox" />
                                                <span>Halland</span>
                                            </label>
        <label class="col m2" style="width: 200px;">
                                                <input type="checkbox" />
                                                <span>Jämtland Härjedalen</span>
                                            </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution I came up with is to use different elements for mobile and desktop and then use absolute positions on the desktop ones.

This is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you use the grid system in MaterializeCSS you need to leave room for the elements even when they are hidden. There isn't an easy way for the columns to dynamically resize.

For your desired result you would need some custom css using the `display:flex` css directive. Here's an example you can adapt:

Codepen: https://codepen.io/nonsintetic/pen/YzrqWjP

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
  $('.input-container.auto-hide').toggleClass("show");
})
```

```css
.menu-container {
  display: Flex;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.input-container {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.input-container input,
.input-container select {
  width: 100%;
}

.input-container.auto-hide {
  display: none
}

.input-container.auto-hide.show {
  display: block;
}

.btn {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  cursor: pointer
}

.btn:hover {
  color: #000;
  border-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu-container">
  <div class="input-container">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="input-container">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="input-container">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="input-container auto-hide">
    <select>
      <option>- Choose -</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="input-container">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="input-container auto-hide">
    <select>
      <option>- Choose -</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="text-align:center">
  <div class="btn">Toggle hidden selects</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I would like to avoid resizing the UI. I came up with a better solution using absolute positions and using different elements for desktop and mobile. I will post an answer with a photo soon.